# Php parse json multiple url

Tags: php, json

I want to parse json from multiple url. I can parse an url with this code:

```
<?php
$url1 = file_get_contents("http://www.url1.com");
$url2 = file_get_contents("http://www.url2.com");

$decode = json_decode($url1);

foreach( $decode as $obj1 ) {
    foreach( $obj1 as $obj2 ) {
        foreach( $obj2 as $obj3 ) {
          foreach( $obj3 as $obj4 ) {
            echo $obj4->name . '<br />';
          }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I want to parse url1 and url2. How can I do that?

Comment: Can You Send Me Your Json ..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `array_merge()` after decode `json`.

```
<?php
$url1 = file_get_contents("json1.json");
$url2 = file_get_contents("json2.json");

$decode1 = json_decode($url1);
$decode2 = json_decode($url2);
$decode_all = array_merge($decode1,$decode2);

foreach( $decode_all as $obj1 ) {
    echo $obj1->name . '<br />';
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
Jaydeep
Manish
```

Comment: Thank you @Jaydeep Mor but this code didn't work. It's give this error
"Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array in /index.php on line 6"
$decode_all = array_merge($decode1,$decode2);

Comment: @Johny your i think you check your `$decode1 ` is Array or not.

Answer (score 0):

> **Myjson1.json File**

```
{
            "name": "xyz",
            "city": "bla bla",
            "state": "bla bla bla"
}
```

> **Myjson2.json File**

```
{
            "country": "bla bla",
            "postal": "000000"
}
```

> **MyPhp.php File**

```
<?php

$url1 = "..\htdocs\myjson1.json";
$json1 = file_get_contents($url1);
$decode1 = json_decode($json1, TRUE);

$url2 = "..\htdocs\myjson2.json";
$json2 = file_get_contents($url2);
$decode2 = json_decode($json2, TRUE);

print '<pre>';
print_r($decode1);
print_r($decode2);
print '<pre> <hr>';

$merge_array = array_merge($decode1,$decode2);

print_r($merge_array);

//http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php
extract($merge_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx"); 


echo "<h1> $name </h1>";
echo "<h1> $city <h1>";
echo "<h1> $state <h1>";
echo "<h1> $country <h1>";
echo "<h1> $postal <h1>";

?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

NOTE: **`wddx_deserialize` Reference** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

> OR ( 2nd Way)

```
<?php

    $decode1 = array("name"=>"xyz","city"=>"bla bla");
    $decode2 = array("state"=>"xyz","country"=>"India");

    $merge_array = array_merge($decode1,$decode2);

    foreach($merge_array as $mydata) {

         echo '<h2>'. $mydata .'</h2>';
    }

?>
```

Demo:  https://eval.in/822392